# Tried installing firebase via cocoapods, error while running XCode project

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I installed cocoapods v1.10.1 and XCode 11, tried to import some pods (Firebase) into the project and this popped up after running it in the simulator.

```
Unable To Install “Creature”
Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: Please try again later.
Recovery Suggestion: Bundle at path /Users/cheng93347/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/34D37C3B-1D32-4F55-80E1-DDC65233F47C/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.M7DJDW/extracted/Creature.app has missing or invalid CFBundleExecutable in its Info.plist
--
Bundle at path /Users/cheng93347/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/34D37C3B-1D32-4F55-80E1-DDC65233F47C/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.M7DJDW/extracted/Creature.app has missing or invalid CFBundleExecutable in its Info.plist
Domain: MIInstallerErrorDomain
Code: 11
User Info: {
    FunctionName = "-[MIExecutableBundle _validateWithError:]";
    LegacyErrorString = MissingBundleExecutable;
    SourceFileLine = 94;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 10.15.7 (Build 19H2)
Xcode 12.3 (17715) (Build 12C33)
Timestamp: 2021-01-17T20:40:53+08:00
```